# how to style my tkinter python code by something like library

Tags: python, tkinter, styles

im looking for a way to style my tkinter code. but i dont wanna do it by myself. is there a library or a way to find beautiful buttons in python code? something like semanticUI or Bootstrap for css.

Answer (score 0):

tbh I don't think you should try to style it, tkinter has default styles and if you want diffrent ones you should make them yourself in html and css.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`ttk` library](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/) (part of `tkinter`) it implements themed `tkinter` widgets. Also if you want even more style, you can use a `tkinter.Canvas` and draw the sprites of the widgets. You can also have events to handle clicking on the sprites/keyboard events but it will take a lot of code to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want nice looking buttons check out this sample program which has tkinter_custom_button.py which is a program someone made for fancy buttons https://github.com/TomSchimansky/GuitarTuner and just import it from the documentation folder. if your looking for premade styles then tkinter is not the place to look and the people who said html or css are right.